# O(1) or O(log(n)) lookup time for records belonging to key on different table

Tags: postgresql

I am looking for a way of accessing all appointments belonging to a particular user in an `O(1)` or an `O(log(n))` fashion. I am currently using a where clause, to which my understanding runs in `O(n)`.

My database schema looks like this.

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (
    username varchar NOT NULL,
    password varchar NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp NOT NULL default current_timestamp,
    updated_at timestamp NOT NULL default current_timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (username)
);

CREATE TABLE appointments (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    user_id varchar NOT NULL,
    doctor_id varchar NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp NOT NULL default current_timestamp,
    updated_at timestamp NOT NULL default current_timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

The way I currently access appointments is this.

```sql
SELECT * FROM appointments
    WHERE doctor_id='doctor_name'
```

Comment: You should stop thinking in abstract terms and think in milliseconds instead; it's more productive. Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: What is n there, the number of matched rows, or the total table size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am currently using a where clause, to which my understanding runs in `O(n)`.

Yes, based on the information you've provided, it doesn't appear that your `doctor_id` is indexed. This means to service your query, that uses it in the `WHERE` clause predicate, a scan of the entire table will need to occur, aka `O(n)`.

> I am looking for a way of accessing all appointments belonging to a particular user in an `O(1)` or an `O(log(n))` fashion.

Sure, just add an index on `doctor_id` like so:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_IndexName ON appointments (doctor_id);
```

Then a B-Tree will be built on the `doctor_id` column, and the search time complexity of filtering on it, such as in your example query, will be `O(log2(n))` roughly.

---

By the way, `SELECT *` is an anti-pattern from a performance, readability, and maintainability standpoint and should be avoided. Instead, always list out only the columns you actually need.

Comment: It should be noted that the logarithm has a large base, so while `O(log(n))` is technically true, the access time is really pretty much independent of the table size.